# ionic app set one chrome/browser version in app

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, integration

I want to set the browser constant in the ionic app. Means the app should use its own
browser not the browser of the device. So there would be no side effects on updating
the chrome/browser of android device.

How can I distribute the browser within the app ?

I found a module
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

But I think this only used on open a url from the app.

It would be great to have any tipp how to integrate the browser.